# Bluetooth Socket Program: connect: Host is down

Tags: wireless, networking, usb, bluetooth, sockets

I am trying to test rfcomm_server.c and rfcomm_client.c (from the link https://github.com/balle/bluetooth-snippets) on my new Bluetooth dongle.

When I run rfcomm_client, it exits on connect giving the error "connect: Host is down". I am running the client with baddr of hci0.

However, "hciconfig" shows the device is up (Mac address changed to XX for the post)

```
hci0: 
Type: BR/EDR Bus: USB BD Address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 
ACL MTU: 310:10 SCO MTU: 64:8 UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN  
RX bytes:706 acl:0 sco:0 events:48 errors:0 
TX bytes:1503 acl:0 sco:0 commands:44 errors:0
```

"hcitool scan" returns the address of one of the paired devices. So I believe the dongle is up. However I am not sure why the connect returns with the Host Down error.

Appreciate any help from the forum.

I am running Ubuntu as a VM on Mac and I have installed "bluez-5.27"

Here are the details of "lsb_release -a"

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty
```